# best web browser in emacs

Tags: emacs

I am frequently following tutorials on the web while writing code, it is tedious to switch back and forth between emacs and the browser.

I have seen some packages as w3m-emacs, however wanted to know if there are any better ones available.

Comment: I would also like to know what methods are available to render html files in Emacs. As for the "research effort", of course, one can view html directly. But I'm talking about rendering.

Comment: I don't think this is an ambiguous or vague question. Reading html help files or tutorials is a big part of programming for many of us, so I think it is on-topic. It's not clear if w3m-emacs is being actively maintained, and it would be good to know what other options are available, and how they compare to w3m.

Comment: Maybe the people who closed this just didn't realize that embedding a web browser in Emacs *is* reasonable? It would be silly for most other text editors, but Emacs definitely *isn't* most other text editors! There are even some projects to embed a full rendering engine (rather than just text), like ezbl. I would certainly love seeing a good answer to this question myself.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: you may be right. Three of the five votes to close were from mods who have not asked or answered any Emacs questions. Not sure why they are even reading Emacs questions, let alone passing judgement on their quality.

Comment: @murtaza52: did you find an answer to your question? I'd be very much interested in it!

Comment: @Martin, I have started using a split screen with chrome on my right and emacs on the left. But I wasnt able to find / install one.

Comment: The WebKit page on EmacsWiki was just updated yesterday with info about the DeepinLinux WebKit extension.  I haven't tried it, but it's a start: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/WebKit

Comment: Emacs 24.4 (not yet released at the time of writing, but you can build from trunk) contains a new elisp web browser named `eww` (accessed via `M-x eww`). It's a work in progress, but it's an immediately useful tool.